# SQL server 2000 how to find transaction history for a table/row

Tags: sql-server-2000, transaction-log

How do you find the modification history for a certain table / row in SQL server 2000? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get a product that can read the transaction log like [SQL Log Rescue](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_log_rescue/index.htm) or [Apex SQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx)

Comment: Is there anyway to examine the transaction log without 3rd party tools?

Comment: What about in transaction log in SQL server 2005/2008? Do they need 3rd party tool to examine?

Comment: Yes. Basically, it not a part that people normally access. If you want to track changes, put in triggers that write to a change history table, or use the 2008 change services.